# Find the volume of the region in space defined by $|x+y+z|+|x+y-z|\le 8$ where $x,y,z\ge 0$.

Tags: linear-algebra

> Find the volume of the region in space defined by $|x+y+z|+|x+y-z|\le
>  8$ where $x,y,z\ge 0$.

I have honestly no idea on how to approach this problem.

By browsing a little bit on the internet I have found a similar question with $x+y+z < 4$ which turns out to be  two tetrahedrons with same base but I don't know how I can (if I can)turn my equation in this form.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: $x,y, \text{ and } z$  are positive, or just $z\geq 0$ ?

Comment: @Nizar, $x$, $y$ and $z$ are positive. @ OP: do you know how to find the vertices of the region?

Comment: @EricS. I suppose so , so why keeping  $x+y+z$ in the absolute value, this confuses me  !!

Comment: @Nizar, ah you're right, I didn't even notice it at first. Indeed unnecessary and confusing.

Comment: @Eric Note that removing the absolute values makes the domain very clear and easier.

Comment: @Nizar, lol I know, I just said 'you're right'

Comment: @EricS. I suppose the vertices are (4,0,0),(-4,0,0),(0,4,0),(0,-4,0),(0,0,4),(0,0,-4) .@Nizar I've written down the above equation as it is stated in my book.

Comment: The problem  is meant to be solved without calculus means.The below answers are too advanced for me.I think I have to define some coordinate axes here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the definition of absoloute value: if $x,y,z\ge 0$ then

$|x+y+z|+|x+y-z|\le 8$ amounts to

$2x+2y\leq 8\Rightarrow x+y\leq 4\ $ if $x+y-z\geq 0$

and

$2z\leq 8\Rightarrow z\leq 4\ $ if $x+y-z\leq 0$

so we can find the limits by integrating first with respect to $x:0\ $ to $4-y\ $ then project onto the $yz\ $plane, obtaining $y\leq 4\ $ whenever $y-z\geq 0\ $ and $z\leq 4\ $ if $y-z\leq 0.$ and this is just the square $[0,4]\times [0,4]$ so the integral is

$\int_0^4\int_0^4\int_0^{4-y} \,dx\,dz\,dy.$

Comment: I don't know any calculus,but thanks anyway for the answer.

Comment: You can think of it as the solid of length 4 built on a triangle of area 1/2 (4)(4).

Comment: Got it. Thanks for your time .

Answer (score 2):

From those inequalities, you have a rather easy space $S$. You just need to notice that your planar section orthogonal to $\vec{n}=(0,0,1)$ does not change trough $z\geq0$. Then it's super simple to define that $$S = \{(x,y,z)\in \mathbb{R}_{+}^3: x+y \leq 4, z\leq 4\}.$$
So,
$$V=\iiint_S d V=\int_0^4\int_0^4\int_0^{4-y} \,dx\,dy\,dz = 32.$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer,but it is too advanced for me right now.

Comment: **Another approach**
Using the absolute function definition, we have that for any $z\leq4$, $x+y \leq 4$. So, this is just a regular prism, with a right isosceles triangle on the basis and height 4. Therefore, we have $$V = h.A_b= 4 \times\dfrac{4 \times 4}{2} =32$$